# How to clean up a broken Virtualbox snapshot (missing files)?

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot

I created a snapshot, in VirtualBox (VBox), and then found it in my HDD. So I deleted it in the folder structure. I saw it was still there when I opened VBox, so tried to remove it but got an error.

I tried removing it in CMD (with Admin rights), but got this error:

```
D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage snapshot "Server Name" delete "Extra HDD Added (no longer available)"
0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Snapshot operation failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not open the medium 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\ExtraHDD.vdi'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\ExtraHDD.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: --------
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not open the medium 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\Snapshots/{e3ef3706-6882-4404-8478-f085ca9f3b1e}.vdi'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\Snapshots/{e3ef3706-6882-4404-8478-f085ca9f3b1e}.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleSnapshot(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 532 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp
```

So basically, I want to remove the "label" of my snapshot, in VBox (as the actual file is not found).

How do I delete it, if it is not found?

Comment: Did you remove the snapshot from VirtualBox snapshot manager before deleting files ? Or you only removed the files ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I removed the snapshot from my `D:\` first (manually). I then went into VBox and tried deleting it and got the above error. So I tried again through vboxmanage and same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the first error by doing this:

```
D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage internalcommands sethduuid "D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\ExtraHDD.vdi" "7ee23ee6-2dd9-4ae0-ae1c-c5ee532fab95"
UUID changed to: 7ee23ee6-2dd9-4ae0-ae1c-c5ee532fab95
```

And now I only have one error left.

```
D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage snapshot "Server Name" delete "Extra HDD Added (no longer available)"
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Shared)" at line 331 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp
```

Last update:

I changed the name of the snapshot (I missed out a `{` in the name), and now I get an even worse error:

```
D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage snapshot "Server Name" delete "Extra HDD Added (no longer available)"
0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Snapshot operation failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not open the medium 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\Snapshots/{e3ef3706-6882-4404-8478-f085ca9f3b1e}.vdi'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VDI: error reading pre-header in 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\Snapshots/{e3ef3706-6882-4404-8478-f085ca9f3b1e}.vdi' (VERR_EOF).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VD: error VERR_VD_VDI_INVALID_HEADER opening image file 'D:\Virtual Machines\VirtualBox\UNIX Machines\Server Name\Snapshots/{e3ef3706-6882-4404-8478-f085ca9f3b1e}.vdi' (VERR_VD_VDI_INVALID_HEADER)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleSnapshot(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 532 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp
```

Unfortunately there is no solution (that I can see) on Google.